# My laptop display/screen doesn't work, is it the hardware?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

Problem: The screen of my laptop doesn't work, not even a "black" back-light. The laptop itself works, the HDD light goes on, it makes sounds etc. etc.

What I tried:

Plugged in an external Packard Bell screen via the VGA, before buying an entirely new screen. This doesn't work, while the external screen does work on a different laptop.

This makes me think it could be:

- the GPU
- some sort of cable issue
- another piece of video-card related hardware I'm unaware of

Laptop: ***HP Pavilion dv2 1160ed***

As far as I could discern (but I am not even sure about that) the video chip or gpu used is [**ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3410**](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/mobility-radeon-hd-3410.c1216), more info on where it is used here:   https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/mobility-radeon-hd-3410.c1216 .  I don't know if it is soldered to the motherboard, or if it's replaceable.

*Question:* **How to fix this problem, as in get this screen working again? Is it the hardware? If not, what software problem could it be?**

*Follow up:* ** The above chip is out of stock, what can I use as a replacement?**

*Also*: **How can I test your solution?**
Any solution will be hard to try, because I can't of course, SEE, anything.

P.S.

- If this question is asked in the wrong way, please tell me how.
- This is a *REPAIR* question, so I'd appreciate it if there's no "buy a new laptop!" remarks.

Comment: Have you checked the RAM? If you have 2 modules try them one by one, if you have only one try reseating it. Try using other known good RAM modul.

Comment: @Leshy Thanks for reacting. Do you mean taking the memory out and putting it back in?

Comment: Yes, for a start. Based on the information you have provided through your question, bad RAM modul is, probably, the best case scenario. If your LP doesn't start working correctly after you try to start it with a known good RAM modul, there is a pretty high probability that your GPU is faulty, which means, You need a new motherboard, so in the end you will have just the 2 options, either buy a new(used) motherboard or buy a new laptop.

Comment: When you've tested external monitor, have you just plugged it in and started the LP without pressing any dedicated button or combination of keys to transfer video output to external monitor - sometimes(on some LPs) you have to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "LP"

Comment: Sry for the late response. "LP" equals Laptop